# How to convert TDateTime to FILETIME?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

title says it all. Internet is full of examples how to convert `FILETIME` to `TDateTime` but not the other way around.

Comment: DateTimeToFileDate(someDateTime);

Comment: DateTimeToFileDate returns Integer not FILETIME.

Answer (score 5):

1. Call `DateTimeToSystemTime` from `System.SysUtils`.
2. Call `SystemTimeToFileTime` from `Winapi.Windows`.

If your original date time value is in local time, then you will need to convert it to UTC before calling `DateTimeToSystemTime`.

Comment: While this is valid, I am not big fan of this solution because of two reasons: 1. I need to use intermediate structure (SysteTime) and calls which are not necessary. 2. I don't know upfront in what time standard my time value is.

Comment: Fan or not, it is the way to do it. Wrap it up in a helper method to hide the details. As far as your second point, you simply have to know what time zone your date time value is given in. You cannot retrieve that information from just a date time value, it simply is not part of the value.

Comment: Since we know that `FILETIME` represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 and we know what TDateTime represents, it is possible to convert one value to another by one function. That is just better than calling two and use intermediate structure. I just thought that somone has done it already. But if no one propose this solution and I will be to lazy to implement it, I will accept yours.

Comment: By using an intermediate `SYSTEMTIME` structure, you lose precision. The better solution is to convert from `TDateTime` to `FILETIME` directly, and not lose 4 decimal places of precision.

Comment: @IanBoyd Interesting. I guess if precision is important, then we should avoid `TDateTime` completely.

Comment: Perhaps. But using `SYSTEMTIME` you have a precision of ±1 ms, contrast that with using `TDateTime` you have a precision of ±0.001 ms. Yes, ±0.001 ms isn't as good as ±0.00001 ms, but that's a lot of precision to give up for nothing. But losing 1 digit of precision is better than losing 5 digits of precision; especially when the alternative is to replace 2 function calls with a multiplication and an addition.

Comment: @IanBoyd I understand that. I'm just taking your point to its logical conclusion.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just pointing at *"Fan or not, it is the way to do it."* I just didn't want anyone thinking it was **the** way to do it.

Comment: @IanBoyd Thank you, I agree

Answer (score 2):

```
function FileTimeToDateTime(AFileTime: FILETIME): TDateTime;
var
    li: ULARGE_INTEGER;
const
    OA_ZERO_TICKS = UInt64(94353120000000000);
    TICKS_PER_DAY = UInt64(864000000000);
begin
    // Convert a FILETIME (which is UTC by definition), into a UTC TDateTime.

    // Copy FILETIME into LARGE_INTEGER to allow UInt64 access without alignment faults.
    li.LowPart := AFileTime.dwLowDateTime;
    li.HighPart := AFileTime.dwHighDateTime;
    Result := (Real(li.QuadPart) - OA_ZERO_TICKS) / TICKS_PER_DAY;
end;

function DateTimeToFileTime(ADateTimeUTC: TDateTime): FILETIME;
var
    li: ULARGE_INTEGER;
const
    OA_ZERO_TICKS = UInt64(94353120000000000);
    TICKS_PER_DAY = UInt64(864000000000);
begin
    // Convert a UTC TDateTime into a FILETIME (which is UTC by definition).

    li.QuadPart := Round(ADateTimeUtc*TICKS_PER_DAY + OA_ZERO_TICKS);
    Result.dwLowDateTime := li.LowPart;
    Result.dwHighDateTime := li.HighPart;
end;
```

By avoiding a [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime?redirectedfrom=MSDN), we avoid [losing precision in milliseconds.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime)

The dwMilliseconds of SYSTEMTIME is, by definition, limited to 1 millisecond resolution.

```
| FILETIME                       | SYSTEMTIME              |
|--------------------------------|-------------------------|
| 100ns resolution               | 1,000,000 ns resolution |
| GetSystemTimeAsFileTime        | GetSystemTime           |
| GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime | n/a                     |
|                   -- FileTimeToSystemTime -->            |
|                  <-- SystemTimeToFileTime --             |
```

You should avoid `SYSTEMTIME`. The purpose of `SYSTEMTIME` is to decode a date/time into it's component parts for you:

- year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond

### Bonus Reading

- [**GetSystemTimeAsPreciseFileTime** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime)
- [**FILETIME** structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)
- [**SYSTEMTIME** structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime)

Comment: The DateTimeToFileTime funtion you made is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at implementation of `ConvertDateTimeToFileTime` in `System.IOUtils`.
It is a private member of `TDirectory` record.
But you can use it as a reference in order to implement all you want in one function.

Comment: Nice find, similar to what @DavidHeffernan had suggested. At this point I don't remember what I've used in my code :)